# Gradle: use -source 15 or higher to enable text blocks

Tags: java, gradle

Not a java dev touching java for the first time, can't get gradle to work.

I'm trying to install [this extension](https://github.com/Toizi/eBPF-for-Ghidra) for Ghidra. The readme says I should run:

```
GHIDRA_INSTALL_DIR=${GHIDRA_HOME} gradle
```

I've installed java 18 and gradle on a mac. When running the above, I get the following error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :copyDependencies NO-SOURCE

> Task :compileJava FAILED
/home/gradle/project/src/main/java/ghidra/app/plugin/core/analysis/eBPFSolanaAnalyzer.java:156: error: text blocks are not supported in -source 11
                    func.setComment("""
                                    ^
  (use -source 15 or higher to enable text blocks)
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Tried running out of docker too (thinking it was a problem with my installation):

```
docker run --rm -u gradle -e GHIDRA_INSTALL_DIR=/home/gradle/project/installed -v "$PWD":/home/gradle/project -w /home/gradle/project gradle gradle
```

But alas get the exact same error.

Why does gradle think I have Java 11 when in fact I have java 18? `gradle -v` gives me:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          18.0.1.1 (Homebrew 18.0.1.1+0)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.4 x86_64
```

This is probably total newb question but like I said I've never touched java:) Any help super appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the project has been configured to be compatible with Java 11, which is why you can't use features from newer versions (even if you run with a newer version).

While I don't know the Ghidra project, you can see from the [build file in the extension](https://github.com/Toizi/eBPF-for-Ghidra/blob/32e33f9c3fed00e8f6077dfe15e5dfb03cd4d889/build.gradle#L43) that it applies a script from the base project:

```
apply from: new File(ghidraInstallDir).getCanonicalPath() + "/support/buildExtension.gradle"
```

Then, if you head over to the Ghidra project and find the [extension file](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/d2883bbb8c9af943625e8d55e67452765056d7eb/Ghidra/RuntimeScripts/Common/support/buildExtension.gradle#L71), you can see that it indeed configures the source and target version:

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = ghidraProps.getProperty('application.java.compiler')
    targetCompatibility = ghidraProps.getProperty('application.java.compiler')
    dependsOn copyDependencies
}
```

These appear to come from the properties file located in [Ghidra/application.properties](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/master/Ghidra/application.properties):

```
application.name=Ghidra
application.version=10.2
application.release.name=DEV
application.layout.version=1
application.gradle.min=6.8
application.java.min=11
application.java.max=
application.java.compiler=11
```

So I would imaging that if you find this file in your local installation, you can change the `application.java.compiler` property to 18. Just be aware that Ghidra might not not actually support it - or it might work just fine; try it out :)